# PDFBox - Rectangle with gradient

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to create pdf using PDFBox library in Java. I have to create rectangle with gradient, but I have no idea how, and can not find anything. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: See the CreateGradientShadingPDF.java example from the source code download. An excerpt of it is in the answer :-) There are 7 different types of gradients, but usually type 2 or 3 are what you want. Enjoy.

Comment: I have seen this, but don't understand. Do you have any documentation about how to create gradients?

Comment: There is only the PDF specification. http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf . The problem is that you'd have to know what kind of gradient you want to create (probably axial), and how it should look, i.e. what colors and where.

Answer (score 0):

Found this example. See if it works for you

```
    COSDictionary fdict = new COSDictionary();

    fdict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 2); // still not understaning that...

    COSArray domain = new COSArray();
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(1));

    COSArray c0 = new COSArray();
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.64176"));
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.72588"));
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0.78078"));

    COSArray c1 = new COSArray();
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.57176"));
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.62588"));
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("0.70078"));

    fdict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, domain);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C0, c0);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C1, c1);
    fdict.setInt(COSName.N, 1);

    PDFunctionType2 func = new PDFunctionType2(fdict);

    PDShadingType2 axialShading = new PDShadingType2(new COSDictionary());

    axialShading.setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    axialShading.setShadingType(PDShading.SHADING_TYPE2);

    COSArray coords1 = new COSArray();
    coords1.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    coords1.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    coords1.add(COSInteger.get(850)); // size of my page
    coords1.add(COSInteger.get(600));

    axialShading.setCoords(coords1); // so this sets the bounds of my gradient
    axialShading.setFunction(func); // and this determines all the curves etc?

    CStr.shadingFill(axialShading); // where CStr is a ContentStream for my PDDocument
```

Comment: I have seen it, and I am able to create gradient on background - and this example creates triangle, not rectangle

Comment: If it creates a triangle then it means you have created a triangle shape before. shadingFill() will fill whatever clipping region and path is active at that time.

Comment: I have just run this code, only I change was values in `coords1` - put there values 0,0,200,100. When I draw a rect before, there was black rect, and triangle gradient behind this rect. The same when `moveTo()` and `lineTo()`.

Comment: @TomaszCzura the coords are not a rectangle, this is the axis for the axial shading. This is a line from (0,0) to (850,600). "Type 2 (axial) shadings define a colour blend that varies along a linear axis between two endpoints and extends indefinitely perpendicular to that axis." see p.185 of the PDF specification. In the code above, c0 and c1 are the two "extreme" colors.

Comment: @TomaszCzura The best would be that you explain what you want, maybe draw it with a color pencil and photograph it, or with a graphics program. Note that PDF coordinates start at the left bottom, not at the left top like in java.